# CSS and div positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create some html using divs instead of my usual tables.

What I want is the `#hdrdetail` div to be displayed under the `#company` div -  the orange div to begin under the green div. I am not sure how I should be using float.

Hope this is enough info to answer.

```css
#maindiv {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100 % ;
      width: 700px;
      margin: auto;
}
#logoleft {
      width: 25 % ;
      float: left;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
}
#company {
      width: 50 % ;
      float: left;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: green;
}
#logoright {
      width: 25 % ;
      float: right;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
}
#hdrdetail {
      float: none;
      width: 100 % ;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: orange;
}
#weekly_lefthdr {
      float: left;
      width: 50 % ;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: blue;
}
#weekly_righthdr {
      float: right;
      width: 50 % ;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <div>
    <div id="logoleft"></div>
    <div id="company"></div>
    <div id="logoright"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hdrdetail">
    <div id="weekly_lefthdr">
    </div>
    <div id="weekly_righthdr">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a little jsfiddle would help a lot. However, please try adding ```clear:left;``` to hdrdetail.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to set `float: none;`, what you should use instead is `clear: both;` ie;

```
#hdrdetail {
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

`float: none` will just unset the float of the element, which in your case wasn't set anyway, whilst `clear: both` will put the element below any floated elements above it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcpfygpt/1/. You need to remove `float:none` in

```
#hdrdetail {
  clear:both;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

and replace it with `clear:both`. The rule `clear:both` sets the condition that "no floating elements would be allowed on either the left or the right side".